# Bundle Install, Ruby on Rails, rubyinstaller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, bundle

I'm completely new to Ruby on Rails, and I'm a few difficulties creating a new rails project.  Each time the 'bundle install' command runs I get the following error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150226-7776-brvf10.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... yes
checking for vm_core.h... yes
checking for iseq.h... yes
checking for insns.inc... yes
checking for insns_info.inc... yes
checking for eval_intern.h... yes
checking for struct iseq_line_info_entry in vm_core.h,iseq.h... no
checking for struct iseq_insn_info_entry in vm_core.h,iseq.h... yes
checking for if rb_iseq_compile_with_option was added an argument filepath..
s
creating Makefile

make  clean
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/debug
1.6.8 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.
bugger-1.6.8/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.8), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.8'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Now I've tried everything from install the debugger version 1.6.8, deleting and then re-installing it, deleting Gemfile.LOCK and creating a new rails project but I still get the error.  I am using the Ruby installer "Ruby 1.9.3-p551" from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ and DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe from the same wesbite.  I tried installing byebug but that isn't compatible with my version of Ruby.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You need to be able to compile `c/c++`, Im not sure about doing that on Windows but I think you can download something from MS to do this.

Comment: Most of the time I recommend doing web dev of any sorts on a **nix* machine as it is easier to do a lot of things such as this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a known issue with rubygems > 2.4.0

try running the command after running this

> gem update --system 2.3.0